# node.js compressing ZIP to memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I want to zip some data into a writableStream.

the purpose is to do all in memory and not to create an actual zip file on disk.

For testing only, i'm creating a ZIP file on disk. But when I try to open `output.zip` i get the following error: "the archive is either in unknown format or damaged". (WinZip at Windows 7 and also a similar error on MAC)

What am I doing wrong?

```
const   fs = require('fs'),
    archiver = require('archiver'),
    streamBuffers = require('stream-buffers');

let outputStreamBuffer = new streamBuffers.WritableStreamBuffer({
    initialSize: (1000 * 1024),   // start at 1000 kilobytes.
    incrementAmount: (1000 * 1024) // grow by 1000 kilobytes each time buffer overflows.
});

let archive = archiver('zip', {
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});
archive.pipe(outputStreamBuffer);

archive.append("this is a test", { name: "test.txt"});
archive.finalize();

outputStreamBuffer.end();

fs.writeFile('output.zip', outputStreamBuffer.getContents(), function() { console.log('done!'); });
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" We can't answer that question unless you tell us the result you're getting and how it differs from the result you expect.

Comment: You are right. I've updated my question. thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not waiting for the content to be written to the output stream.

Comment out `outputStreamBuffer.end();` from your code and change it to the following...

```
outputStreamBuffer.on('finish', function () {
    fs.writeFile('output.zip', outputStreamBuffer.getContents(), function() { 
        console.log('done!');
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. when i open the ZIP file i see another file called output.zip.cpgz

Comment: Updated my answer @YoniMayer. Try it. Worked for me.

Comment: @Matt 'finish' is called after 'end', so that's I final event. Any particular reason you want to use 'end'?

Comment: Thx it is working now.
Can you explain why i should not call end directly?

Comment: Awesome! By the time you call `end`, the content you wrote into `archive` hasn't been streamed into the `outputStreamBuffer`. So you end up with an empty/partial stream. Since you are calling `finalize` on `archive`, calling `end` is not required (it's implicitly taken care of).